# TypeScript: passing props to children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I have a problem on how I will pass my props to a children:

```
interface RootState {
  sideIsOpen: boolean;
  isOpen: boolean;
}

const SideNavigation: React.FC = () => {
  // const { sideIsOpen } = useSelector((RootState) => RootState.toggleSide);
  const selectIsOpen = (state: RootState) => state.sideIsOpen;
  const sideIsOpen = useSelector(selectIsOpen);
  return (
    <SideNav>
      <LogoNavigation isOpen={sideIsOpen} />
    </SideNav>
  );
};
```

and my children:

```
const LogoNavigation: React.FC = (props) => {
  return (
    <LogoSide>
      <img src={Logo} alt="Logo Elo Ghost" />
    </LogoSide>
  );
};
```

i got this error:

> Type '{ isOpen: boolean; }' is not assignable to type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.   Property 'isOpen'
>   does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode;
>   }'.ts(2322)

Comment: Could you provide some info of `LogoNavigation`?

Comment: Likely `isOpen` is not a property of `LogoNavigation`.

Comment: i want pass isOpen to LogoNavigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to declare that your`LogoNavigation` component expects to get `isOpen`.

You can do it with interface, it should be something like this: (It was'nt tested)

```
interface InterfaceName {
  isOpen: boolean
}

const LogoNavigation: React.FC<InterfaceName> = ({isOpen}) => {
  return (
    <LogoSide>
      <img src={Logo} alt="Logo Elo Ghost" />
    </LogoSide>
  )
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello I had done this but for some reason I use this state to enable two types of styles in my component, but for some reason it is not working, could you look at this question?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61427095/emotion-js-hamburger-animation

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare LogoNavigation component so that it accepts isOpen prop.
for that you can define a interface or do it like below

```
function LogoNavigation(props: { isOpen: boolean }) {

  return <div />;
}
```

Comment: dont work same error on isOpen and error on LogoNavigation

Comment: Type '(props: RootState) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is missing the following properties from type 'RootState': sideIsOpen, isOpents(2322) on LogoNavigation

Comment: and Type '{ isOpen: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'isOpen' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)